# Which country's laws apply to buying/selling illegal items? Buyer, seller or owner of the service?

Tags: united-states, internet, international, european-union

Assuming user *A* (in country *I*) sells stolen virtual accounts to the user *B* (in country *II*) on the [darknet market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darknet_market) using service owned by user *C* (in country *III*) which is hosted on the web server (hosted in another country *IV*) . Also assuming this activity is illegal in all party's countries (not to mention communication is [onion routed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_routing) through several other countries), no physical postage is involved and hosting company doesn't know about illegal activity on their server.

Who's breaking the law, user *A* (seller), user *B* (buyer) or the owner of the illegal service - user *C* (which is in different country than his service is hosted)? Or all of them, but in different ways (different paragraphs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you've said, user A and user B are breaking the law. User C is breaking the law only if facilitating the activity is illegal in a jurisdiction that they may be prosecuted in and if no safe harbor provision applies.

The fact that onion routing occurs is irrelevant to the legality of the activity, though it may be relevant to questions of evidence.

Without more specific information, I can't write a more specific answer.